# Why is the a:visited font color overriding the font color of the link

Tags: html, css

Why is the `a:visited` font color overriding the font color of the link? Is there any way of getting the link's original color?

```css
nav  {     
    display: table;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

nav > ul  {
    display: table-row;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: table-cell;
}

header > nav > ul > li > a:link {
    color: #eeda11;
}

header > nav > ul > li > a:visited {
    color: rgb(71, 235, 16);
} 

header >  nav a:hover, header > nav a:active {
    background-color: rgba(133, 43, 243, 0.89);
}  

header > nav > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #eeda11;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;

}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Kitchen Bar</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
       <li> <span id="searchIcon"><img src="images/searchBar.png" width="20px"               
         alt="Search Bar"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: please describe your issue properly.

Comment: use the same color for visited what you are using for link

Comment: try `a:visited { text-decoration: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 issues:

1. There is no `<header>` in the supplied code.
2. After `nav`, you forgot `>`, so you got `nav a:hover`

```
nav > a:hover, header > nav a:active {
  background-color: rgba(133, 43, 243, 0.89);
}
```

Working snippet:

```css
nav  {     
    display: table;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

nav > ul  {
    display: table-row;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: table-cell;
}

nav > ul > li > a:link {
    color: #eeda11;
}

nav > ul > li > a:visited {
    color: rgb(71, 235, 16);
} 

nav > a:hover, header > nav a:active {
    background-color: rgba(133, 43, 243, 0.89);
}  

nav > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #eeda11;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;

}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kitchen Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    <li> <span id="searchIcon"><img src="images/searchBar.png" width="20px"               
         alt="Search Bar"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```